# How to handle browser related popup?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to handle browser related popup?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: Code only answers may solve the original question, but having some explanation makes a much better answer as it helps others understand why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which pop up do you mean?
 at a later time I suffered with this, but it was actually a tab inside another using ajax calls, I resolved with waits, explain your problem better and maybe I can help you